# Showing $\left(\frac{\sum a_{i}+1}{2}\right)^{2}\geq \sum a_{i}^{2}.$

Tags: inequality, summation, contest-math, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Given $a_{i}\in \left [ 0;1 \right ]$, $i=1,2,...,2019.$ Prove that:
$$\left(\frac{\sum a_{i}+1}{2}\right)^{2}\geq \sum a_{i}^{2}.$$

I think it is a very fantastic inequality. From  $a_{i}\in \left [ 0;1 \right ]$, I only get $a_i^2 \leq a_i$. I made an effort to use AM-GM but it is not effective. What is the mothod to solve this kind of problem? Give me the solution or any great ideas please, thank you in advance!

Comment: From where does it come from?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry, I can not remember. It was in my notebook for a long time without any solution! Please show me some ideas, thanks.

Comment: user628755 used AM-GM! It's not very effective...

Comment: The presence of $2019$ suggests this is a contest problem from this year, possibly an ongoing one.

Comment: imagine your summation has only 1 term. Write that equation and it will be a perfect square greater equal than cero which is always true. Use the same approach for all terms

Comment: @eyeballfrog no, it was in my notebook for a long time, we can replace 2019 to another number, maybe...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2019}a_i^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^{2019}a_i$$ and we need to prove that
$$\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2019}a_i+1}{2}\right)^2\geq\sum_{i=1}^{2019}a_i,$$  which is true by AM-GM:
$$\left(\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2019}a_i+1}{2}\right)^2\geq\left(\frac{2\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2019}a_i}}{2}\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^{2019}a_i.$$
I used the following.

Let $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2019}a_i=x$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2\geq x$$ and by AM-GM:
$$\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2\geq\left(\frac{2\sqrt{x\cdot1}}{2}\right)^2=x.$$

Comment: I  still can not understand your idea, can you give me a solution please?

Comment: I'd change 'we need to prove that' to 'it suffices to prove that'

Comment: @user628755 I added something. See now.

Comment: Thank you so much, it is easy-understanding now!

Comment: i think that he need to understand how you get the $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{2019}(a_1-1)\right)^2\geq0$

Comment: @EduardoS. Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Eduardo S It was my typo. I fixed. It should be $\left(\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2019}a_i\right)-1\right)^2.$

Comment: Michael, he need to prove $\left(\frac{\sum a_{i}+1}{2}\right)^{2}\geq \sum a_{i}^{2}$ and you answer is proving $\left(\frac{\sum a_{i}+1}{2}\right)^{2}\geq \sum a_{i}$

Comment: @user628755 I wrote my solution by AM-GM.

Comment: @Eduardo S. See please a first line of my proof.